# Know if the user receive the firebase push notification or not

Tags: android, firebase, curl, firebase-cloud-messaging

When we send Firebase Push Notification to a device using curl command. We get a unique id as Response from firebase. Is there any option or possibility to know If Push Notification has been received by the receiver?

for example i use this curl command to send a fcm notification to my device with my token device

`curl -i -H 'Authorization: key=AAAAqE23LvI:APA91bFVCR6rZAsim4i8PU57sx_nSQ4Z7fOwKQ2WYHRi4UDINtnMZq-lCA_KIqXEdD3XQthhPr7qhiCdb0XKGuhCJiWY2rr2DFUvaQnLDLZA8JXl4UoMXGsVkJsIzRZ6oNGszMa0EBRy' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPOST https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send -d '{"data":{"title":"Using Curl","message":"this notification is send through Curl","image-url":"your_image_url"},"to": "fHwLWZlqRyuAqxIKz_NgVb:APA91bE3WV57SOjy7DIbyOaEpgX-Qj4V2lRXyBeLpbWOTAtaN9w1OH__41dunGjC-Iv1mGCoALVI5ZtreCcYCg7lnnsHN-nWXqpbgaTdzvbzuEdSrViO81qxKtmpnt-UsurwFTiJ_paK"}'`

Now the response is an unique id

**i need to know if i can use this id to know if the notification is recived to the user or still pending**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API to detect whether a specific messages was received by the target app/device in Firebase Cloud Messaging. If you need such functionality, you will have to build it yourself - for example by writing the information to a database yourself when your Android code is triggered for the message.